# Firebase + GeoFire : Goequery with different radius

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I would like to know if it's possible to do that and if it is, how is it possible to do so : 
With Geofire and AngularJs, I would like to display all the elements in the A area with
A = lat,lng + radius:25km
It's easy with a geoquery to do that **but if**
B = lat,lng + radius:8km
C = lat,lng + radius:20km
D = lat,lng + radius:5km
**C area is in the A area as you can see in the image below :** 
[image]

Is it posible to retrieve all the elements like C wich are crossing and sharing areas with Geoquery ?
Can you please tell me how to execute this ?

Thank you

Comment: There is nothing built in to GeoFire for this. You will have to run two geo queries and then keep your own list of items that are in both.

Comment: I understand thank you but it will be easy to do like you said if I only had 4 items for exemple but I have 1000 items to search in and compare ...